# CMD line vs PHP script

Tags: php, curl

I can run a curl command in PowerShell and it works, but does not when I try to move to a php script (php also run from the command line)
Command line:

`curl.exe https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/a1b2c3d4/v3/customers/attributes -H "x-auth-token: a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Returns:

```
{"data":[{"id":2,"name":"gp_customer_id","type":"string","date_created":"2021-12-14T14:18:10Z","date_modified":"2021-12-14T14:18:10Z"}],"meta":{"pagination":{"total":1,"count":1,"per_page":50,"current_page":1,"total_pages":1}}}
PS C:\Users\JAMESB\Documents\webroot\BC\swamp
```

PHP file:

```
$ACCESS_TOKEN = "a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4";
$STORE_HASH = "a1b2c3d4";

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "x-auth-token: $ACCESS_TOKEN";
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'ACCEPT: application/json';
var_dump ($headers);
    echo "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/$STORE_HASH/v3/customers/attributes\n";
$state_ch = curl_init();
//    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/$STORE_HASH/v3/customers/attributes");
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/a1b2c3d4/v3/customers/attributes");
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($state_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
var_dump($state_ch);
    $state_result = curl_exec ($state_ch);
var_dump($state_result);
    $state_result = json_decode($state_result);

var_dump($state_result);
?>
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>   string(45) "x-auth-token: a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4a1b2c3d4"
[1]=>   string(30) "Content-Type: application/json"     
[2]=>   string(24) "ACCEPT: application/json"}
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/a1b2c3d4/v3/customers/attributes  resource(4) of type (curl)  bool(false)  NULL
```

Thanks!
Jimbus

Comment: try to use `curl_error` to get more details about error

Comment: In the real code, do you have the correct store hash in `CURLOPT_URL`? Why don't you use the variable `$STORE_HASH` there?

Comment: @Barmar it's there, but commented out. Desperate for things try, I thought maybe the inline variable might be the issue and hard coded it, It is consistent, throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_exec()` is failing (it returned `false`)

Try calling `curl_error()` to see why:

```
$state_result = curl_exec ($state_ch);
if ( ! $state_result) {
    print(curl_error($state_ch) . PHP_EOL);
}
```

Note: The "ACCEPT" header may not be correct. I've never seen any in all caps, and I can't remember what the specs say about that. Also, you don't show an ACCEPT header in your command-line version.

Comment: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

I understand the error, but I'm not sure the difference between running on the CMD line and in a script in the same environment

Comment: Header names are case-insensitive, there shouldn't be a problem with all caps.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer (and it's the same as one someone else already made). With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

DaveAM's answer got me to an error:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

From there, another stackoverflow answer had this:

> The above steps, though helpful, didnt work for me on Windows 8. I
> don't know the co-relation, but the below steps worked. Basically a
> change in the cacert.pem file. Hope this helps someone.
>
> Download cacert.pem file from here:
> http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html Save the file in your PHP
> installation folder. (eg: If using xampp – save it in
> c:\Installation_Dir\xampp\php\cacert.pem). Open your php.ini file and
> add these lines:
> curl.cainfo=”C:\Installation_Dir\xampp\php\cacert.pem”
> openssl.cafile=”C:\Installation_Dir\xampp\php\cacert.pem” Restart your
> Apache server and that should fix it (Simply stop and start the
> services as needed).

Which worked beautifully! I'm a newbie and don't have enough rep to like Dave's answer. I'd appreciate if if you'd show him some love :)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the quoted answer? Also, you should be able to accept the above answer as correct even without rep.